# How to throw 404 exceptions in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to use the Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler to handle my error 404 cases. 
According to the [doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler), the plugin has constants that one can use to match Exception types and handle them accordingly. e.g.

```
switch ($errors->type) {
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
            // 404 error -- controller or action not found
```

Does anyone know how to create exceptions of these types specifically?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
```

or

```
throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('This page does not exist', 404);
```

Comment: For Zend 2 [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968331/zend-2-how-to-throw-a-404-error-from-controller)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
return;
```

Comment: I believe correct method is setHttpResponseCode not setStatusCode

Answer (score 1):

I always land here when googling this, so the answer for Zend Framework 2, Zend Framework 3 and also Laminas is (in case you're using the MVC module):

```
$this->response->setStatusCode(404);
return $this->response;
```

You must `return` inside of the action and **make sure you return the response object**! Otherwise it's possible that you expose more data then you want too!

If you're using [Psalm](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm) and get an error, because `{Laminas|Zend}\Stdlib\ResponseInterface` doesn't know `setStatusCode()`, you must do a type check before:

```
 use Zend\Http\Response as HttpResponse;
 // ...
 if ($this->response instanceof HttpResponse) {
     $this->response->setStatusCode(404);
 }
 return $this->response;
```

**For doing a 404 in Zend Expressive or Laminas Mezzio [then please refer to the documentation](https://docs.mezzio.dev/mezzio/v1/cookbook/custom-404-page-handling/).**