# Zend 2: How to throw a 404 error from controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to throw a '404 Page not found' error from my controller. How can I do that?

I use Zend Framework 2 not 1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
return;
```

in your controller's action method.

Comment: I just have to wait 10 more minutes. :)

Comment: This no longer works for me.  It tries to render the page anyway.

Comment: Cleaner to do it like this: $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
return $this->getResponse();

Answer (score 37):

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function previewAction ()
    {
        return $this->notFoundAction ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the correct ZF2 setup you should already have your 404 view, then in your controller action just use the following and the 404 is automatically handled for you:

```
   if($notTheCorrectSlugMatchOrWhatEver){
   return  $this->notFoundAction();
   }
```